# How to specify the path to a dependency located in my home directory in Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, toml

I want to use a local package which is located in my home directory. By default, Cargo searches for dependencies relative to Cargo.toml. If I know where my project is located relative to the home folder, I can do something like this:

```
[dependencies]
tools = { path = "../../rust_libs/tools" }
```

I don't always know where my project is located and I would like to do something like this:

```
[dependencies]
tools = { path = "${HOME}/rust_libs/tools" }
```

How can I get the home path inside of Cargo.toml? Maybe there are other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try `~/rust_libs/tools`?

Comment: @Dmitry yes. It just appends this path to Cargo.toml path and shows error. "Unable to update /Users/vladas/dev/sand/rust_sand/~/rust_libs/tools"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to workaround this issue with native linux soft links:

1. Create a soft link to `~/rust_libs/tools` in your `Cargo.toml`'s directory using commad:

```sh
ln -s ~/rust_libs/tools
```

2. In `Cargo.toml` just use relative path:

```
[dependencies]
tools = { path = "tools" }
```

Answer (score 4):

It should work if you use a path that starts with '/' which should be recognized as an absolute path.  If the path starts with ~/ or $HOME/ and there is no env variable expansion, then those paths will look like a relative path, and cargo will prepend the current path.  I don't think Cargo.toml supports substituting environment variables, so you will have to specify the whole path (ie. `/Users/vladas/rust_libs/tools`)

Comment: It works for paths starting with '/'. Thank you. But with this approach i still need to know user name and also the path will be different on windows and linux. Is there a way to make it crossplatform?

Comment: @VladasZs Sorry it's not clear what you did. How did you get it to work?

Comment: ```[dependencies]
tools = { path = "/Users/vladas/rust_libs/tools" }
```

Comment: I can't get it to work on Windows. Complains about invalid path no matter what I try.

Comment: @Miscreant checkout my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows:

```ini
dioxus-web = {path = "D:/github/dioxus/packages/web"}
dioxus-desktop = {path = "D:\\github\\dioxus\\packages\\desktop"}
```

Both are working.